# Laravel Delete a Cookie

Tags: laravel, cookies

When the user press the reset button on the filter, I want to delete the cookie that I previously created to save the user inputs and redirect to the same page "/search/influencers". I have searched all over stackoverflow and none of the listed ways to delete the cookie works. Please help!

```
/**
     * resets the cookie that holds previous filter query
     */
    public function resetFilter(Request $request){
        if(Cookie::has('if_query_pref')) {
            Cookie::queue(
                Cookie::forget('if_query_pref')
            );
        }



        return redirect()->route('influencerSearch'); //change the expiration time
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems like fine, Please check that after removing cookie, it shouldn't reassign cookie.

**I have used following code to remove cookie.**

```
public function resetFilter(Request $request){
    return redirect()->route('/influencerSearch')->withCookie(Cookie::forget('if_query_pref'));
}
```